# Cannot Serialize/Deserialize ArrayList

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize an array list with a object inside:

```
HairBirt param = new HairBirt();
param.setName("name");
param.setValue(2.3f);

HairBirt param2 = new HairBirt();
param2.setName("name2");
param2.setValue(2.4f);

ArrayList<HairBirt> list = new ArrayList<HairBirt>();

list.add(param);

list.add(param2);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
try {
    bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    obj_out.writeObject(list);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String encoded = bos.toString();
try {
    encoded = URLEncoder.encode(encoded, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.print("The serialized output is: " + encoded);   

//DECODE

ArrayList<HairBirt> paramDecoded;

String myParam = null;
try {
    myParam = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Got parameters");
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(myParam.getBytes());

try {
    ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);

    paramDecoded = (ArrayList<HairBirt>) obj_in.readObject();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The HairList object is also a serializable object.

This code execution is returning the following error:

> `java.io.InvalidClassException: java.util.ArrayList; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8664875232659988799, local class serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189`

in line `paramDecoded = (ArrayList<HairBirt>) obj_in.readObject();`

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Can you give a tip?

Update:

**Resolved:**
Just used a native array of HairBirt instead of a ArrayList and it works:

```
HairBirt[] list = new HairBirt[x];
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<HairBirt> list = new ArrayList<HairBirt>();
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()` - instead, use `toByteArray()` and base64-encode that binary data to convert it into a string without losing information.

I strongly suspect that's the main problem - that you were losing the data after serialization. You should probably also close or at least flush the `ObjectOutputStream`. I don't know offhand whether that actually does anything in this case, but it would seem to be a good idea.

I don't believe there's any base64 support directly in Java (in a public class, anyway) but there are various 3rd party libraries you can use, such as [the one in the Apache Commons Codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).

Comment: Yup, that's the problem, but i really need to use String on that move... This is not the real problem, it's a simplification of it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'on that move'? You will *have* to convert the BAOS to a string in a lossless way if you want to be able to deserialize it. Whether that's with base64 or not is a different matter, but I think it's a good way of doing it.

Comment: @sakana: base64 is a string format with a limited character set.

Comment: What do you mean by 'on that move'? 
I mean that I really need to use a String between the Encode and Decode code. It's the only parameter type i'm able to use.

Comment: That's fine - that's why you use base64 to convert from byte[] to String without losing information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overriding this behavior by declaring your own serialVersionUID in your custom class?

Do you have a specific reason for doing the extra step of serializing through a string? Normally you would just deserialize through an ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Declaring a serialVersionUID doesn't help here.

Comment: @MichaelMyers How did you know that? The error message clearly states that the serialVersionUID is different between serialization and deserialization. This usually happens if the class was changed in between and no ID was previously defined.