# Getting NotSerializableException on a serializable object

Tags: java, serialization, io

Basically, I've written a program that paints shapes onto the screen, and saves each of the shapes into an ArrayList. What I want to do is figure out how to save the ArrayList to a file, so that I can call it back up later and edit the already existing shapes.

So I've been having some trouble figuring out why exactly I keep getting a NotSerializableException when I made the object Shape serializable already.

Below is the save portion of my code, and the Shape object.

```
save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(BallWorld.this);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
      File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
      ArrayList list = bp.shapes;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
      try{
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(list);
        oos.close();
      }
      catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
  public class Shape implements Serializable{
    int radius;
    Point center;
    Color color;
    int sides;
    Polygon shape;
    public Shape(int _radius, Point _center, Color _color, int _sides){
      radius = _radius;
      center = _center;
      color = _color;
      sides = _sides;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 
      g2d.setColor(color);
      shape = new Polygon();
      if(sides != 0 && sides != 4){
        if(sides % 2 == 0){
          if(sides / 2 % 2 == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < sides; i++){
              shape.addPoint((int) (center.x + radius * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides - Math.PI / sides)), (int) (center.y + radius * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides - Math.PI / sides)));
            }
          }
          else if(sides / 2 % 1 == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < sides; i++){
              shape.addPoint((int) (center.x + radius * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides)), (int) (center.y + radius * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides)));
            }
          }
        }
        else{
          for(int i = 0; i < sides; i++){
            shape.addPoint((int) (center.x + radius * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides - Math.PI / 2)), (int) (center.y + radius * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides - Math.PI / 2))); 
          }
        }
        g2d.fillPolygon(shape);
      }
      else if(sides == 4){
        g2d.fillRect(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
      }
      else{
        g2d.fillOval(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
      }
      repaint();
    }
    public boolean contains(Point p){
      if(sides == 0){
        if(center.distance(p) <= radius){
          return true;
        }
      }
      else if(sides == 4){
        if(p.x <= center.x + radius && p.x >= center.x - radius && p.y <= center.y + radius && p.y >= center.y - radius){
          return true;
        }
      }
      else{
        if(shape.contains(p)){
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

---

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$AcceptAllFileFilter
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLabel.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.ArrayTable.writeArrayTable(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at BallWorld$2.actionPerformed(BallWorld.java:112)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Be sure all the attributes of you Shape objects are Serializable too like Point, Color and so on..

Comment: I've already examined all of those classes, and all of them are Serializable

Comment: Did you look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678481/cannot-serialize-deserialize-arraylist

Comment: @lordraiden15: If they *were* all serializable, you wouldn't get this error. You've missed something, but we can't see the whole picture from here.

Comment: Also, we need to see the stack trace.

Comment: @skaffman I updated the question to include the stack trace. Also, I did check each of the objects that are used to create the Shape object, and they are all serializable.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid NotSerializableException make sure:

1. **your class** implements Serializable
2. all non primitive **members** implement Serializable (or are transient instead)
3. if your class is an **inner class** it's either static or the outer class implements
   Serializable

Besides that you also need to define **serialVersionUID** for every Serializable class. Check all 3 cases above plus:

1. all Serializable **superclasses**
2. if your class is an **anonymous class**, define it there too

Note: your code may work without serialVersionUID sometimes but [read the last paragraph in Serializable's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) to understand why it will be a problem depending on the environment.

---

There's a VM option to add details to the exception. It shows the root and nested classes failing to serialize:

```
-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true
```

Comment: If it's an inner class it can't be static.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the call you are making to `repaint()` in Shape, I'm guessing that it is in inner class. It therefore has a hidden variable referencing its enclosing instance. It will try to serialize that object along with itself. Is the outer class serializable? Or better yet, could Shape be made into an ordinary top-level class?