# Serialize an ArrayList of Date object type

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I want to serialize an Arraylist containing Date objects and then be able to de-serialize it and iterate over the de-serialized version.

Currently I have a class called DateSerialize that implements Serializable. I have a method for adding date objects into the arraylist and then once that is done i want to serialize it.

Next time when i run the program i want to deserialize that arraylist and get those objects in the same order and format and want to run an iterator over it.

Can anyone help me out with this ??

Thanks !

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I was trying the normal type of serialization such as serializing a boolean variable.
But i am not sure if it will work, as i read a couple of articles that said i need to have an arraylist that contains objects that are serializable and all... it didnot make much sense to me... so i was wondering if you could give me a solution to this problem !!

Comment: If you read 5 articles to make sure what you do will work before trying something, you won't go very fast. Try something, test it, and if it doesn't work, think about what the problem might be. It's 1 line of code to test.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of...the below one..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678481/cannot-serialize-deserialize-arraylist?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678481/cannot-serialize-deserialize-arraylist?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Serializable, you should have no problems, because ArrayList is Serializable just as String and every primitive type. `public class DateSerialize implements Serializable {}` should do the rest. You can read more about this method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). However there are a lot of other options for serialization. So please be more specific.

### EXAMPLE

#### First: Creating the ArrayList and the object to put in

```
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
MyBusinessObject obj = new MyBusinessObject();
obj.Name = "MyName";
obj.Address = "MyAddress";
obj.Phone = 435345;
aList.Add(obj);
```

#### Second: serializing the ArrayList

```
/// <summary>
/// Serialize the ArrayList
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string SerializeArrayList(ArrayList obj) { 
  System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  Type[] extraTypes = new Type[1];
  extraTypes[0] = typeof(MyBusinessObject);
  System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList), extraTypes); 
  System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(); 
  try { 
    serializer.Serialize(stream, obj); 
    stream.Position = 0; 
    doc.Load(stream); 
    return doc.InnerXml; 
  } catch { throw; } finally { 
    stream.Close(); 
    stream.Dispose(); 
  } 
}
```

#### Third: deserializing the ArrayList

```
/// <summary>
/// DeSerialize serialized string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="serializedData"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private ArrayList DeSerializeArrayList(string serializedData) {
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
  Type[] extraTypes = new Type[1];
  extraTypes[0] = typeof(MyBusinessObject);
  System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList), extraTypes);
  XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(serializedData));
  try {
    object obj = serializer.Deserialize(xReader);
    list = (ArrayList)obj;
  } catch { throw; } finally {
    xReader.Close();
  }
return list; 
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for this mate !!

Comment: @Nisarg Thank you for listening my advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do not store `DateSerialize` as `long` (internal value of date in milliseconds)?